# To count the number of vowels in the string(python)

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
word='azcbobobegghakl'

cout=0

for leter in range(word):

    if leter=='a' or leter=='e' or leter=='i' or leter=='o' or leter=='u':  

        cout += 1

print('Number of vowels: '+ str(cout))
```

I'm getting error:

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Very close... `for leter in word` is fine - no need for the `range`....

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But I thought that range would get the individual letter from "word" and check it for the condition or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chosen for leter[sic] in range(word) in stead of `for leter[sic] in word`:

In your python console try this:

```
>>> range("word")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is the error that you are getting.

This should fix your code:

```
word='azcbobobegghakl'

cout=0

for leter in word:

    if leter=='a' or leter=='e' or leter=='i' or leter=='o' or leter=='u':  

        cout += 1

print('Number of vowels: '+ str(cout))
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the fixed version but as to explanation. You are using range(word). Word is a string while range expects a number. If you need length of a word you can use len().

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you that range is a function which gives you list of values to the limit in **integer** i.e range(10) will give me 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.
This applies to numbers only.
You could change it as
 `for letter in word:`
or

```
`for letter in range(len(word)):`





  `if word[leter]=='a' or word[leter]=='e' or word[leter]=='i' or` word[leter]=='o' or word[leter]=='u':  





cout += 1
```

This is bacuse len(word) gives me the length and range of that gives me an iterator to iterate from 0 to len-1
now I can use indexing to access each letter
Here is my code though:

```
 word='azcbobobegghakl'

cout=0

for leter in word:



if leter=='a' or leter=='e' or leter=='i' or leter=='o' or leter=='u': 





 cout += 1

print('Number of vowels: '+ str(cout))
```

or

```
word='azcbobobegghakl'

cout=0

for leter in range(len(word)):



if word[leter]=='a' or word[leter]=='e' or word[leter]=='i' or word[leter]=='o' or word[leter]=='u':  
cout += 1

print('Number of vowels: '+ str(cout))
```